# PHP: json with null values showing as empty when using json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have json that has does include null values. I still want to capture those null values but when I use json_decode the null values are changed to empty within the array. Is there a way to preserve the null values after using json_decode or change the empty values to a value other than empty?

```
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 51136
    [key] => 18
    [fields] => Array (
        [ticket] =>
)
```

In this array I want to change "ticket" to something other than blank or it would also be ok if the original null value is preserved when using json_decode.

Original json data:

```
"id": "51136",
"key": "18",
"fields": {
    "ticket": null,
          }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `null` will preserved, could you show your original data?

Comment: added snippet of the original json

Answer (score 0):

> change the empty values to a value other than empty?

You can use `array_walk_recursive` for this..

```
array_walk_recursive($yourarray, function (& $item, $key) {if (is_null($item)) { $item = "N/A"; }});
```

The call-back function checks your array for `NULL` values , and if found it replaces with `N/A`